# How can I get the a message No data found message from the Kendo ComboBox when the user give wrong input to Combo textbox

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to prevent the users to give wrong input and if they type anything other than from the combo list, it should give the message 'Not Data Found'.  How is it possible from my code given below and now it is not working when the user type any value or edit change other than from the list and if they do , it should be checked with datasource

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox(m=> m.CustomerId)
    .Value(Model.CsutomerId == 0 ? string.Empty: Model.CustomerId.toString())
    .Filter("contains")        
        .DataTextField("CustomerName")
        .DataValueField("ID")
    .HtmlAttributes(new {@class="form-control",@id="custinfo" })
    .Placeholder("Select Customer...")
        .AutoBind(true)
        .DataSource(source => 
    {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetCustomer", "Customer");
            }).ServerFiltering(false);
        })
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .Events(e => e.change("onCustomerChange").DataBound("OnCustomerDataBound"))
    )
```